# How can I assign lineEdits to some variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qlineedit

I am new to working with Qt. And I got stuck at this thing. I have a lot of lineEdits in my application, And the values in it may change any time while the application is running. Values in lineEdits would be only integers. At some stage I need to check the values in lineEdits and compare with an integer array. If they are equal, then the task for user is completed.

Here I want to store all values of lineEdits to an integer array so that I can run a `for` loop to check if both the arrays are equal instead of making an `if` condition for each and every `lineEdit`. Values in array should get updated whenever user changes the value in lineEdit and also value in lineEdit should change when its corresponding value in array changes.

I tried taking a qvector, appending values of lineEdits into it. This vector now has values of lineEdits but does not update values when its corresponding values are changed in vector.

Can anyone please help in how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a list of pointers to `QLineEdit`s as a class member :

```
QList<QLineEdit *> lineEdits;
```

And add the pointer to linedits to the list when instantiating them :

```
QLineEdit * lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
lineEdits->append(lineEdit);
```

Then `QSignalMapper` is useful to update array of values when the line edits are updated. `QSignalMapper` class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal. So you can have one like:

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QObject::connect(mapper,SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SLOT(OntextChanged(int)));
```

For each of your line edits you can connect the `textChanged()` signal to the `map()` slot of `QSignalMapper` and add a mapping using `setMapping` so that when `textChanged()` is signaled from a line edit, the signal `mapped(int)` is emitted:

```
for(int i=0; i<lineEdits.count(); i++)
{
    QObject::connect(lineEdits[i], SIGNAL(textChanged()),mapper,SLOT(map()));
    mapper->setMapping(lineEdits[i], i+1);
}
```

This way whenever you change a line edit, the `mapped(int)` signal of the mapper is emitted containing the index of the line edit as a parameter.

The values of the array could be updated in the `OntextChanged` slot like :

```
void MyClass::OntextChanged(int index)
{
   values[index-1] = lineEdits[index-1].text().toInt();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using QDataWidgetMapper because it would use model/view design pattern which has several advantages. Below is an example that clearly shows that the data in all QLineEdit's can easily be summarized. The example contains two files main.cpp and mainwin.h:

**mainwin.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWIN_H
#define MAINWIN_H
#include <QtGui>
static const int lineEditCount=4;
class MainWin : public QMainWindow
{
      Q_OBJECT
      QStandardItemModel& model;
   public:
      explicit MainWin(QStandardItemModel& m)
      : model(m)
      {
         setWindowTitle("QDataWidgetMapper Example");
         resize(400,400);
         QDataWidgetMapper* mapper=new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
         mapper->setModel(&m);
         QWidget *w = new QWidget;
         QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
         w->setLayout(layout);
        for(int i=0;i<lineEditCount;++i)
        {
           QLineEdit* e=new QLineEdit;
           layout->addWidget(e);
           mapper->addMapping(e,i);
        }
        layout->addWidget(new QTextEdit);
        setCentralWidget(w);
        mapper->setCurrentIndex(0); // the only existing row is activated
        reactToChange(0);
        connect(&m,SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)), 
                 this,SLOT(reactToChange(QStandardItem*)));
      }
   private slots:
      void reactToChange(QStandardItem*)
      {
         QTextEdit* t=findChild<QTextEdit*>();
         t->append("=========================");
         for(int i=0;i<lineEditCount;++i)
            t->append(model.item(0,i)->text());
      }
};
#endif
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mainwin.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    /* Create the data model. It has only one row, but as many columns as there are
       QLineEdit. */
    QStandardItemModel model(1,lineEditCount);
    for(int column = 0; column < 4; ++column)
    {
      QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("QLineEdit %0 value").arg(column));
      model.setItem(0,column, item);
    }
    MainWin mainWin(model);
    mainWin.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Each time any of the `QLineEdit` change then a new summary of the values in all the `QLineEdit` is presented, see below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Qt is all about signals and slots. In your case, you need to connect the `lineEdit`'s text edited signal to the variable you want to modify. In the dialog where you have the `lineEdit`, you should have a connection in the constructor such as:

```
connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, &YourDialog::textEdited);
```

This will connect the `lineEdit`'s `textEdited` signal to `YourDialog`'s slot which I also named to `textEdited` for this example.

This slot should take a single argument that is a `const QString&`, because that's what `QLineEdit::textEdited` is emitting according to Qt's documentation.

Then, you can do whatever you like inside this slot function, such as converting the input to an `int` with `lineEdit->text().toInt()` and assigning its value to an array element, etc.

Also, if you are sure that the only entries should be `int`s to this `lineEdit`, in the constructor, you can use a `QIntValidator` object with `lineEdit->setValidator` to ensure that the user edits the `lineEdit` value to a valid integer within a range specified by you.